# API to detect if code completion popup is active?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm only in my first hour of using VS Code, trying to get the environment just right, in this case, being able to tab out of quotes and brackets. I found this [extention](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=albert.TabOut), but it breaks the native 'tab-to-complete' code completion. I set out to fix the extension, thinking there must be a way to tell if the code completion popup is active in the editor and defer the first tab to it - but I have been unable to glean any useful information from the [VS Code API](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api).

My coding skills are hobbyist at best, so I'm hoping a simple 'if' statement somewhere will fix it, but any information will help.

Comment: Checkout the new version: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=albert.TabOut